# NSURLConnection not calling delegate method

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to make connection using NSURLConnection with my server. I have implemented this many time before but currently its not calling its delegate methods in any case(success/failure/timeout). I cannot understand why it is happenning.

Below is the code which I have written.

in .h i have implenented NSURLConnectionDelegate

in .m

This is getting called, I have checked by putting log.

```
 self.connection = nil;
 self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:MyRequest delegate:self    startImmediately:YES];
```

My connection object is not nil.

Delegate method which i have impleneted are

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection
```

I have putted logs in all of them but none of them is getting called.

I have also checked my sever, & its working fine.
I am also connected to internet.

Any one can throw some light, what I am missing.

Comment: Have you tried to use `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` instead of `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using both but same problem

Comment: Can you add more code ? When and how do you create the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem got resolved.

I called my createConnection on main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is better solution that won't block your connection delegate callback if you are scrolling tableview etc.:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self  startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

Certainly You also can call NSURLConnection in other thread. Check out the example in [github](https://github.com/hrchen/ExamplesForBlog).